# Scala apply cannot return Option

Tags: scala, scala-option

I recently tried using `apply` like a factory function:

```scala
class X() {
    def apply() : Option[X] = if (condition) Some(new X()) else None
}

val x : Option[X] = X() // <- this does not work; type is mismatched
```

For some reason `apply` **always** returns `X`. Would I need to create a `Factory` method?

Comment: Can you post the full-code? `X` is a class, but it is being used as a value in `Some(X)` and `X()`

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Sorry I forgot the parenthesis :P EDIT: and the `new` keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to define `apply` in the companion object. Then, you need to specify specifically `new X()` in order to the compiler to know to use the original `apply` method, instead of trying to create `X` recursively.

```scala
case class X()

object X {
  def apply(): Option[X] = {
    if (Random.nextBoolean()) Some(new X()) else None
  }
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OySiaeRIT3ufORmJYCV8zQ).

Comment: Thank you, this made it work. So I shouldn't put the `apply` method in the class in favor of the object? (Just to be clear)

Comment: @JaackoTorus if the method is inside the class then you can not call it without first creating an instance of the class. If you want something like a static method then it has to be defined in the companion object.